# Compare two lists and add the ones that dont match the requirement to another list

Tags: c#, list, telerik

I want to compare two lists and add the ones that dont match my requirements to another list. I've really have no idea how I should do this.

What I've tried:

```
var componentForThisProject = mdal.Get_MethodComponents_Of_Project(project.Id);
var shapelist = this.diagram.Shapes;


var newlist = (from shape in shapelist
           where componentForThisProject.Any(
               p =>
               p.X_coordinate == Math.Round(shape.Position.X, 0) &&
               p.Y_coordinate == Math.Round(shape.Position.Y, 0)
               )select shape).ToList();
```

This work, but as you see this does the opposite what I want it to do. It adds everything that match. I've ofcourse tried to change the == operator to != but then it just adds everything to my new list.

I'm using Telerik btw.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
            var newlist = (from shape in shapelist
                   where !componentForThisProject.Any(
                       p =>
                       p.X_coordinate == Math.Round(shape.Position.X, 0) &&
                       p.Y_coordinate == Math.Round(shape.Position.Y, 0)
                       )select shape).ToList();
```